# How can I fix "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I tried to install a fresh installation of Laravel 5 on my Mac.  I'm stuck already, and I just started.

I run : `composer create-project laravel/laravel l5`

I got this error

[image]

This is what I have in `composer.json`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to install Laravel 5.1? It is not released yet.

It should be

```
"laravel/framework": "~5.0"
```

Comment: This composer.json is created for me at some point. I didn't know that. Let me try.

Comment: Fix it, run `composer update`, see this stupid error : composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is...

Comment: Error :  `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` still showing

Comment: So your missing the php `ext-mcrypt` extension. You need to add that to your PHP. See this: http://laravel.io/forum/05-30-2014-mcrypt-php-extension-required?page=1