# Laravel 5.2: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages(duplicate)

Tags: json, composer-php, laravel-5

I think question is almost same but error is different.
I just install laravel 5.2 and trying to install [quickadmin](https://packagist.org/packages/laraveldaily/quickadmin) packages. But I got this error. I also update composer. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601137/i-get-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages) suggestion and also some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505023/how-can-i-fix-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of) suggestions. But It's not working. I also tried older version of composer.json configuration. But unfortunately It's not working.
**Error:**[image]
**Here is my Composer.json configuration without changing anything.**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Any suggestions how to solve in laravel 5.2?

Comment: It looks like you just need to enable your php_fileinfo extension in your php.ini file; that's what the error is saying when you install composer.

Comment: Intervention/Image needs PHP GD library which you probably haven't included in php.ini

Comment: Thanks @ChrisForrence. It's working. Just removing the semicolon from the line extension=php_fileinfo.dll of php.ini file. I didn't notice this error first . Actually I was noticing the upper problem. Now It's working.  without including PHP GD library  It's successfully installed @ sef4eg 2.